# Find the equation of the parabola with its vertex on the line $2y-3x=0$?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Its axis of symmetry is parallel to the x-axis, and it passes through the two points $(3,5)$ and $(6,-1)$

Comment: What issues have you can with this problem?

Comment: i get stuck at having two simultaneous equations, that i can't seem to solve

Comment: If the axis of symmetry is parallel to the X axis, we're talking x=y^2, not the usual y=x^2. That's a start.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** Instead of solving for $x$ and $y$, which won't get you anywhere, write $x=a(y-h)^2+v$ and solve for $a$, $h$, and $v$. (Since the axis of symmetry is parallel to the x-axis, the parabola must be in this form.) Then you have your equation.

**Hint 2:** Note that $(v, h)$ are the coordinates of the vertex (this parabola is not oriented in the "classical" fashion). Since this is on the line $2y-3x=0$, we have the equation $2h-3v=0$. But we're solving for three variables, so we need two more equations. Luckily, we have two points...